# How to run c++ program written in eclipse, from terminal

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, terminal

I'm using Ubuntu and I have written my c++ code in Eclipse Neon.
My workspace contain 4 projects. The main project is called BaseCppProjectRun (it contains main.cpp file) and I have other projects with these names: Encoders, frmwrk, NetworkLayer - the BaseCppProjectRun using each one of them.

If I running my program directly from eclipse everything works.
But I want to running my program from terminal - and I can't.
Because When I'm trying to run my progrm like this:

```
root@ubuntu:/builds/BaseCppProject/BaseCppProjectRun# ./Debug/BaseCppProjectRun
```

I'm getting this error:

```
./Debug/BaseCppProjectRun: error while loading shared libraries: libfrmwrk.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

As I said before, if I'm running it directly from eclipse everything works.

How can I run my program from terminal?

Comment: Are your shared libraries in the same folder as the executable (or otherwise visible for it)? My guess is 'no'. I don't write C++ code in Eclipse, but for Java there is the option to export an 'executable' and package libraries along with it. Is there maybe a similar option for C++? Otherwise you could just copy the libraries by hand.

Comment: the default runtime loader doesn't look in the same directory as the executable. This, luckily, isn't windows.

Comment: @JeromeReinländer I tried to copy my so files to the same directory of my executable file. I got the same error.

Comment: @YaronIsraeli ... read my comment directly below Jerome's comment...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out!

Refere to Marcus Muller's answer + my steps this is how I have fixed it ( all steps via terminal):

1. Create new directory in my workspace directory and called it libs.
2. In each one of your projects do: right click > c/C++ Build > Build Steps (tab) and in Post-build steps paste this:

```html
cp ${BuildArtifactFilePrefix}${BuildArtifactFileName} "${WorkspaceDirPath}/libs/"
```

This code copy the so files directly into your libs directory when you compile your program.

And finally, in your terminal execute this:

```html
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/builds/BaseCppProject/libs/
```

Now you can run your program via terminal.

Answer (score 2):

How is Linux supposed to know where to find libfrmwrk.so, if you don't put that either where it normally looks nor tell it where it can be found.

Eclipse seems to set up the paths the runtime linker looks into so, that when your program is loaded, the runtime linker knows where to find your libfrmwrk.so and so on.

You'll either have to

- install these libraries (.so's) so that they are found in default locations, or
- set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to contain all the folders to look into.

I haven't worked with Eclipse CDT in ages, but you can by now probably export some project formats that allow you to easily install things.

Another thing: It seems you're running software you're still debugging as root: That is a terrible idea, and if it can be avoided, avoid it.

Comment: I tried to copy my so files to the same directory of my executable file. But I'm getting the same error.

And about the second option using LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I don't know how to use it. So if you have any example and where I edit this argument it may help a lot

Comment: Why do you think that would even help?! My answer especially said what would help, and copying the files to the same folder is not among that.

Comment: Can you please give more information on how to do these steps:
install these libraries (.so's) so that they are found in default locations, or
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to contain all the folders to look into.

Comment: Setting the LD_LIBARAY_PATH didn't help..
I tried to do this in terminal:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/builds/BaseCppProject/frmwrk/Debug/";"/builds/BaseCppProject/Encoders/Debug/";"/builds/BaseCppProject/NetworkLayer/Debug/"

and then:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Then I tried to run my program again. But I'm getting the same error.

Comment: The LD_LIBRARY_PATH value wasn't right. but still with the right one it doesn't work.
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/builds/BaseCppProject/frmwrk/Debug/:/builds/BaseCppProject/Encoders/Debug/:/builds/BaseCppProject/NetworkLayer/Debug/"